# He of all wonders

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice

Now let us praise the guardian of Heaven's kingdom,
The creator's might and His purpose,
The work of the the Father of glory, as He of all wonders,
Eternal Lord, established the beginning....

As he of all wonders or as he is of all wonders?

Comment: ..as he, of all wonders, x, established y.

Comment: Can u explain more....and I have put the comma on the right place as It is written in the book.

Comment: Can you tell us where you found this sentence?  It looks like a translation of [Caedmon's Hymn](https://public.wsu.edu/~delahoyd/medieval/caedmon.html) and the language is very old-fashioned and poetic.  I would say that **as** in this sentence means something like **because**, so you would not add "is" to it.

Comment: I found this in a Book entitled 'A critical history of English literature' by David Daiches... chapter name- Anglo Saxon literature.....but we can add 'is' after 'because'..as because is conjunction and there should be a finite verb after it.

Comment: No, you cannot add "is" here, because it would not make sense.  **established** is the finite verb. This sentence is very hard to parse because of the old-fashioned writing style, but if I am reading it correctly "He of all wonders" is like a parenthetical.  Think of the sentence like this: "I talked to John, because he, the company's president, had the most knowledge."

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we're just being asked about a bad translation

Answer (score 1):

This is Caedmon's hymn, or a Modern English translation.  The orginal is *swa he wundra gehwæs* literally "so he wonders' every's"

Old English is very concise, The word order is different unlike modern English it uses few words but has lots of complex word endings including a "real" genitive case. "as he of all wonders" is a fair translation into modern English, using "of" instead of the genitive. "He of all wonders" is a description or epithet of God.

"Swa" mean "so" or "in that way" or "while" or "as". "When" might be an alternative translation to "as".